# How to add static content before the feed on the front page?

Tags: theming

I want my front page to contain some static content (a short description of our association), and after that the normal feed of articles fed by "promote to front page".  How can this be achieved?

I know how to add content to the front page feed and I know how to change the front page to another page, but I couldn't figure out how to get both static content and the front page feed.  (It seems such obvious and often-wanted functionality for a front page...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Serpiente's answer gives several valid options, but I prefer yet another.  The Views module comes with a view that emulates the default home page.  Enable this view, set it as your home page, and add your static text as a Header section.

One advantage to this method is that it gives you more control over the items in the front-page feed.  Some day, you may decide that static text in the header is not quite flexible enough, and then you can change your Header to show another view.

If you are not already using Views, this is a good way to start.  In D8, Views will be in core, and the front page (as well as most or all of the admin pages) will be implemented as views.

[image]

Comment: After some more work on the site we found the Views module to be very useful otherwise as well, and we changed the home page to use this method as well.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways to do this:

## 1. Use the default block system

Create a new block `admin/structure/block/add` and insert your headline (or none) and the body text. Under `Visibility settings` select `Only the listed pages` and insert `<front>`. Select under region the region where the block shall be shown, or do this at `admin/structure/block` after saving the block.

## 2. Use [panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) + page manager (ctools)

Create a new panel page and make this page your frontpage, put the feed you want to be displayed inside of the main area, add a custom content pane before that feed/ view.

## 3. page.tpl.php

inside of your templates page.tpl.php you can add a codeblock for your custom content, [drupal_is_front_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) will help your here:

```
<?php
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  //your custom code
}
?>
```

reference for bartik: [page.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!bartik!templates!page.tpl.php/7) with bartik you could use the `$is_front` variable as well for detection.

Comment: Used the first method, works like a charm.